Como ejecutar un script en el sistema actual? ya que me menciona que este archivo no esta firmando digitalmente. (VSC)
ng : No se puede cargar el archivo
C:\Users\choquesita\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1. El archivo
C:\Users\choquesita\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 no está firmado
digitalmente. No se puede ejecutar este script en el sistema
actual. Para obtener más información acerca de la ejecución de
scripts y la configuración de la directiva de ejecución, consulta
about_Execution_Policies en
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1

ng new practico-angular
~~

CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityExce
ption
FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess




Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! seguiste el link que se te recomendo?? tenes que decirle a vs code que ese entorno es seguro...

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
